# JSF Managed bean method does not triggered when form is submitting

Tags: jsf, cdi

I made a form to add some data to my database. This is my html coding. When I click the submit button, the `go()` method doesn't trigger. Why is that?

```
<form jsf:id="formAddDesignation">
                            <br/>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-4">Designation Name</div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <input type="text" required="true" jsf:value="#{designationBean.designationName}" placeholder="Designation name" jsf:id="designationName" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-4">Designation Description</div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" jsf:value="#{designationBean.designationDescription}" placeholder="Designation description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="row" style="padding-right:  54px">
                                <button type="submit" jsf:id="btnAddDesignation" jsf:action="#{designationBean.go()}" class="btn btn-default col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-8 pull-right">Login
                                    <f:ajax  execute="formAddDesignation" render="logs" />
                                </button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

**Managed Bean (CDI)**

```
@Named(value = "designationBean")
@RequestScoped
public class DesignationBean implements Serializable {

    private String designationName;

    private String designationDescription;

    private Boolean status;


    public DesignationBean() {
        System.out.println("dddeeeee");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        status = false;
        System.out.println("ddddddddd");
        designationName = "dddd";

    }

    public String getDesignationName() {
        return designationName;
    }

    public void setDesignationName(String designationName) {
        this.designationName = designationName;
    }

    public String getDesignationDescription() {
        return designationDescription;
    }

    public void setDesignationDescription(String designationDescription) {
        this.designationDescription = designationDescription;
    }

    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
        System.out.println("status");
    }

    public String go(){
        System.out.println("Method is clicked");
        return "clicked";
    }

}
```

Comment: 'does not trigger' is very limited information. Is the request send to the server. Any errors in whatever logging? Did you check everything on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked

Comment: and if I remember correctly, type="submit" is not needed, but I'm not sure (don't use the 'html friendly way' myself

Answer (score 0):

Try only "designationBean.go" without the parenthesis. As far as I remember, you dont put parenthesis!

Comment: Do tell me if it was the issue or not!